# pwmconfig no longer detecting sensors since reinstalling 14.04

Tags: 14.04, temperature

My computer has a Asus P8H61-M PRO motherboard and I was previously able to use fancontrol to control the fanspeeds. It detected the sensors as w83627ehf.

I've recently reinstalled Xubuntu 14.04 as I wanted a fresh installation and I wanted to rearrange my partitions. sensors-detect is now telling me to use nct6775. I've used modprobe to load up nct6775 but when I run pwmconfig it tells me "There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed" and sensors only lists the coretemp temperatures. If I try to modprobe w83627ehf it tells me "Device or resource busy".

I've tried installing the latest versions from https://github.com/groeck/nct6775 to no avail. It's slightly frustrating that all of this was working fine before I reinstalled, so I know that it has to be possible, but I just need to get the right version of something from somewhere.

Does anybody have any suggestions for next things to check please?